# Cloning filter function using ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I need help implementing my own version of the .filter() method using a ternary operator.

```
const s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myFilter = function(callback) {
  this.forEach(a => callback(a) === true ? newArray.push(a) : //??? )
  return newArray;
};

var new_s = s.myFilter(function(item) {
  return item % 2 === 1;
});
```

How do I complete this? What do I put in place of "//???"?

Comment: If you don't want the other path, consider using `&&` instead of `?` Also `newArray` doesn't exist in the example

Comment: `callback(a) === true` this check is not needed if `callback` returns a boolean

Comment: If you're not using the the return value or the else operand of the conditional operator, you probably shouldn't be using it.

Comment: "implementing my own version of [built-in function]"... um, why?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Looks like an exercise task.

Comment: @andreas That's my thought, but this is a terrible use of the ternary operator so if that's the exercise I question the lessons...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `null` if `callback(a)` is not true. Also, `newArray` is not defined in your example.

```js
var s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myFilter = function(callback) {
  const newArray = []
  this.forEach(a => callback(a) === true ? newArray.push(a) : null )
  return newArray;
 };

 var new_s = s.myFilter(function(item) {
   return item % 2 === 1;
 });
 
 console.log("s:", s)
 console.log("new_s:", new_s)
```

Here, the use of a ternary operator is not necessary, or even a hindrance since you do not need the else branch. There is also the question if the result of callback really has to be `true`, or if `truthy` is enough. The auxiliary array is also obsolete.

```js
 const s = [23, 65, 98, 5];

Array.prototype.myFilter = function(callback) {
   return this.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
     if (callback(currentValue)) {
        accumulator.push(currentValue)
     }
     return accumulator
    }, []);
};

const new_s = s.myFilter((item) => item % 2 === 1);
     
console.log("s:", s)
console.log("new_s:", new_s)
```

Comment: Since the real `.filter` only requires truthy I suppose that's the way to go.